# dlmalloc free pointers

Tags: linux, c, heap, libc

I was looking at the implementation of "free" in my current dlmalloc(both the source and the disassembly). However, I could not find the code section the inserts the FD and BK into free chunks. What is the blob of code responsible for doing that? Where and when are those pointers inserted?

Comment: I do not find a dlmalloc on my linux distro.  Perhaps you should post the code and clarify 'FD' and "BK'

Comment: ftp://g.oswego.edu/pub/misc/malloc-2.6.2.c ; I'm using the linux distro here : https://exploit-exercises.com/protostar/